# How I can give a php page a style from my theme

Tags: php, theme-development

I have a page made in PHP, a developer gave it to me, but there is no styling in it. How can I give it the same theme like my website theme?
Or to render it inside a page in WordPress
[This is the page](http://quranbooks.net/en/sura-and-ayat-lists/) and this [is my website](http://quranbooks.net). I want the same theme to that page too!

Answer (score 1):

There are three css files in your *not-styled-like-my-theme* page and none of them are coming from the writr theme.

The goal you want is to get the writr theme's css on that page.

Unfortunately, I did this in Google Chrome and the results are probably not what you're looking for.

[image]

This means your page and theme appear to be incompatible, unless that is indeed what you want. In which case, in the Appearance->Editor, you could find the file that your *not-styled-like-my-theme* page is and add a few lines in the header for the css file from your theme.